# querySelector returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="~" class="dm-post-0 well clearfix post listview"
    data-identifier="~" data-relative="https://~"
    data-feed="~">

let convertEntries = () => {
  "use strict";
  let target = [...document.getElementsByClassName("listview")];
  target.forEach((element) => {
    result.push({
      url: element.querySelector("#listview").dataset.relative,
    });
  });
  return result;
};
```

How can I capture the contents of the `data-relative` attribute instead of returning `undefined`?

Comment: `url: element.getAttribute("data-relative")`

Comment: @ITgoldman Why is that better that `.dataset.relative`?

Comment: `element` is already the element with the `data-relative` attribute, you don't need to call `.querySelector()`. `element.dataset.relative`

Comment: @Barmar Just a personal preference, not introducing another property

Comment: @it-goldman: Of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over these elements in the HTML collection returned by `getElementsByClassName` you only need to get the dataset value from the *current iterated element*.

```
element.dataset.relative
```

Since you're doing an array-like collection => array conversion you may as well use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build the array of objects to save declaring a separate `result` array.

And [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is shorter to type.

```js
function convertEntries() {
  const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.listview')];
  return list.map(element => {
    return { url: element.dataset.relative };
  });
}

console.log(convertEntries());
```

```html
<div id="~" class="dm-post-0 well clearfix post listview" data-identifier="~" data-relative="https://~" data-feed="~">
<div id="~" class="dm-post-0 well clearfix post listview" data-identifier="~" data-relative="https://~1" data-feed="~">
```